# Read values from .txt file to vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, io

I have data in a text file, which contains varying amount of columns at each row in the text file. The data I have is at following format:

> 2
>
> 21 2623
>
> 707 40 1

After there's three numbers in a row the data remains at the same structure until the end of file. I want to process the data so I have three vectors X, Y and Z, which contains the values from rows which have three numbers, so that:

> X = 707
>
> Y = 40
>
> Z = 1

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i dont know version of your matlab, in my version(R2013b) I can do this with the following: 1)selecting import(in home ,variable menu) 2) select my file 3)select matrix in imported data menu 4)select exclude rows with unimportable cells in unimportable cells menu 5)and select import selection from import menu

Comment: Is the number of non-3-numbered rows constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of rows to ignore is *not* constant and you want to do this programmatically rather than using the import wizard, you'll first need to figure out how many rows there are to ignore.

One method to do this would be to use [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html), which goes through a file line-by-line. Once you have the number of headers you can then read in the data with a function like [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) or [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

For example:

```
fID = fopen(myfilepath, 'r'); % Open data file for reading

ncoldesired = 3;

ii = 0;
% Search for the first row of "good" data
while ~feof(fID) % Loop will stop if it reaches the end of the file
    tline = fgetl(fID);
    temparray = str2num(tline); % Convert string to array of doubles, could also use regex

    if length(temparray) == ncoldesired
        % Found the first row of data
       nheaders = ii;
       fclose(fID);
       break
    end

    ii = ii + 1;
end

% Error Catching
if exist('nheaders', 'var') == 0 && feof(fID) 
    fclose(fID);
    error('End of file reached, no good data found');
end

mydata = dlmread(myfilepath, ' ', nheaders, 0); % For some reason dlmread uses zero-based indexing unlike everything else in MATLAB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to store the first three rows, you can use either `textscan`
specifying the property `'headerlines' 3` or dlmrear specifying the property `'roffset'` 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't need to store the data from rows which contains less than three numbers, I'm only interested in rows which contain three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`cellfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`cell2mat`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

```
 rowContainsThreeElems = cellfun(@(x) size(x,2)==3, tline_c);

% // Get those rows 
A= cell2mat(tline_c(rowContainsThreeElems==1))
A =
   707    40     1
```

---

```
% //    Data.txt
% //    --------------
% //    2
% //    21 2623
% //    707 40 1

% // Read in the file and convert it to an array
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
tline = fgets(fid);
tline_c = {};
n = 1;
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
     % // Convert the line to a numeric array but store it in a cell array
    tline_c{n} = str2num(tline);
    tline = fgets(fid);    
    n=n+1;       
end
fclose(fid);

% // Get the lines that have three elements
rowContainsThreeElems = cellfun(@(x) size(x,2)==3, tline_c);

rowContainsThreeElems =

   0   0   1

% // Get those rows 
A= cell2mat(tline_c(rowContainsThreeElems==1));
ans =

   707    40     1

% // Add them to X,Y,Z  
X=A(:,1); Y=A(:,2); Z=A(:,3);
```